# How to use reflection to retrieve the values from snippet like below

Tags: java, reflection

I need to log the values of each object. The type of object may vary every time, i am trying to invoke getters of class using reflection. But i am stuck at a place where i need to reinvoke readData method, if class is a Custom Object. how to get an object to pass in readData(obj) in else block below.

```
private static void readData(Object resp) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
    Method[] allMethods = resp.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    for (Method m : allMethods) {
        if ("get".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName().substring(0, 3))) {
            Class<?> type = m.getReturnType();
            if (isWrapperType(type) || type.isPrimitive()) {
                System.out.println(m.invoke(resp)) ;
            }
            else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
                if(m.getGenericReturnType() instanceof ParameterizedType){
                    ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) m.getGenericReturnType();
                    System.out.println("List is of type "+(Class<?>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
                }
                //iterate the object and recall read data with generic type of collection

            }
            else{
                //Problem : need to pass object from type, how do i get this class object, as it should not be any new instance
                readData(obj);
            }

        }

    }

}
private static final Set<Class<?>> WRAPPER_TYPES = getWrapperTypes();

public static boolean isWrapperType(Class<?> clazz)
{
    return WRAPPER_TYPES.contains(clazz);
}

private static Set<Class<?>> getWrapperTypes()
{
    Set<Class<?>> ret = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    ret.add(Boolean.class);
    ret.add(Character.class);
    ret.add(Byte.class);
    ret.add(Short.class);
    ret.add(Integer.class);
    ret.add(Long.class);
    ret.add(Float.class);
    ret.add(Double.class);
    ret.add(String.class);
    ret.add(BigDecimal.class);
    ret.add(Number.class);
    return ret;
}
```

This is how BO's look like

**Response.java**

```
public class Response {
    List<OrderStatusList> orderStatusList;
    StatusResponse        response;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**StatusResponse.java**

```
public class StatusResponse {
    protected String type;
    protected String message;

    // getter-setter
}
```

**OrderStatusList.java**

```
public class OrderStatusList {
    Header header;
    // getter - setter
}
```

**Header.java**

```
public class Header {
    protected String orderNumber;
    protected String orderStatus;
    protected List<DtOrderStatusResponseList> item;

    //getter-setter
}
```

**DtOrderStatusResponseList.java**

```
public class DtOrderStatusResponseList {
    protected String orderItemNumber;
    protected String orderItemMaterialNumber;
    protected String orderItemRequestedQuantity;
    protected String orderItemStatus;

    //getter-setter
}
```

Comment: Avoid logging [PII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information), or at least mask it if it's really needed.

Comment: To the extent of understanding of your question, you need some solution to avoid these multiple getters and setters? is that correct what I understood?

Comment: no, i just need to read the values in these objects, but since i have a large number classes i will have to manually do a get operation on these object and if it is a list i need to iterate and do a get operation. I want to avoid doing the same thing for each class and rather looking for a solution to execute these get methods irrespective of object type

Answer (score 0):

Since you only need to log the values and not use them Overwrite the Object#toString method in all the Classes that hold information you want.
With this approach you can effectively have the information of every Object in one line.

For example

```
public class SOFTest {
    privat int age, weight, height;
    private Header header;

    //Constructor etc.

    @Overwrite
    public String toString() {
        return "SOFTest(" + String.format("%s, %s, %s %s)", age, weight, height, header.toString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: But in this case i will have to go to each class and override toString(), and i have more than 200 classes with each having huge number of data members with again a custom object.
 Best solution i could think was to write a method using reflection that could act as a common method for any object being passd

Comment: In your Snippet you only had 3 classes!
Look into this Tutorial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html

Answer (score 0):

I need to invoke the getter to the object of the custom class in readData(), so pass method.invoke(resp). It would be like this :

```
private static void readData(Object resp) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException {
Method[] allMethods = resp.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
for (Method m : allMethods) {
    if ("get".equalsIgnoreCase(m.getName().substring(0, 3))) {
        Class<?> type = m.getReturnType();
        if (isWrapperType(type) || type.isPrimitive()) {
            System.out.println(m.invoke(resp)) ;
        }
        else if(Collection.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            if(m.getGenericReturnType() instanceof ParameterizedType){
                ParameterizedType paramType = (ParameterizedType) m.getGenericReturnType();
                System.out.println("List is of type "+(Class<?>) paramType.getActualTypeArguments()[0]);
            }
        }
        else{
            //Solution : need to invoke the getter to get the object and it would work
            readData(method.invoke(resp));
        }

    }
  }
}
```